# Next.js 13 + Multer No HTTP methods exported in Export a named export for each HTTP method

Tags: next.js, multer

Package.json Version

Next : 13.4.12
prisma : 5.0.0
next-connect : 0.13.0
multer : 1.4.5-lts.1

```
//schema.prisma
model User { 
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  profileImage String?
  createDate   DateTime @default(now())
  updateDate   DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

All I'm trying to do is upload an image to profileImage

```
//app/api/user/route.ts

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import multer from "multer";
import nextConnect from "next-connect";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: './uploads',
      filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, file.originalname),
    }),
});

const apiRoute = nextConnect({
    onError(error, req, res:any) {
      res.status(501).json({ error: `Error ${error.message}` });
    },
    onNoMatch(req, res) {
      res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
    },
  });
  
  apiRoute.use(upload.single('profileImage'));
  
  apiRoute.post((req, res) => {
    const profileImagePath = (req as any).file.path;
    const user = prisma.user.create({
        data: {
            profileImage: profileImagePath
        }
    })

    res.status(200).json({ user });
  });
  
export default apiRoute;

export const config = {
    api: {
      bodyParser: false,
    },
};
```

I tested the API with PostMan, but I got a 405 error.
error Detected default export in 'app/api/user/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.

error No HTTP methods exported in 'app/api/user/route.ts' Export a named export for each HTTP method.

I don't know why this issue happens every time I test with Postman, what should I fix?